# Oracle Apex user creation

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application where you can add data: your name, address, phone number and email address, and I would like to create an Apex user with the email and a password "password" to log-in. When you logged in, you have access to certain pages.

So it would be a dynamic user generation based on the data you provide in the Text Fields.

Do you have any idea how i could manage to do that?

It should be something like a webshop where you register and then you have access.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by defining authorization scheme and authentication scheme for the current page. you can use  **Custom** Authentication schema for dynamic user creation.
To have different access to different user is controlled by authorization schema.
Search section "8.2.2.8 Security" or Authentication or authorization into url 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/bldr_pg_edit_att.htm#HTMDB25152